# ASP.NET Core API - ActionResult<T> vs async Task<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

If I'm creating an API using .NET Core 2.1 with some typical POST and GET methods, which return type for those methods is most suitable, `ActionResult<T>` or `async Task<T>`? One of my friends uses the latter in every API he creates and that's what was used by the company I was on placement with, whereas the tutorial on PluralSite uses the former. I understand what each one does, but I'm unsure of which should be implemented for any given HTTP request?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ASP.NET Core offers the following options for Web API controller action return types:

- `Specific type (T)`
- `IActionResult`
- `ActionResult<T>`

### Specific type (T):

The `Specific` return type is appropriate when you need to return primitive or complex data type without further checking with possibility of different return type (BadRequestResult (400)`,`NotFoundResult (404)`, and`OkObjectResult(200)`.)  from the action as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Product>> GetProducts()
{
    return await _repository.GetProductsAsync();

    // Here you can not return Ok(products), NotFound() etc;
    // If you need to return NotFound() etc then use `IActionResult` instead of Specific type.
}
```

### IActionResult type:

The `IActionResult` return type is appropriate when multiple `ActionResult` return types are possible in an action as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductById(int id)
{
    Product product = await _repository.GetProductByIdAsync(id);

    if(product == null)
    {
        return NotFound(); // Here is one return type
    }

    return Ok(product);  // Here is another return type
}
```

The `ActionResult` types represent various HTTP status codes. Some common return types falling into this category are `BadRequestResult (400)`, `NotFoundResult (404)`, and `OkObjectResult(200)`.

### `ActionResult<T>` type:

**ASP.NET Core 2.1** adds new programming conventions that make it easier to build clean and descriptive web APIs. **`ActionResult<T>`** is a new type added to allow an app to return either a response type or any other action result (similar to **`IActionResult`**), while still indicating the response type.

**`ActionResult<T>`** is more specific to Web APIs in **ASP.NET Core >= 2.1** and  `ActionResult<T>` offers the following benefits over the `IActionResult` type:

- The `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute's Type property can be excluded.
  For example, `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Product))]` is
  simplified to `[ProducesResponseType(200)]`. The action's expected
  return type is instead inferred from the `T` in `ActionResult<T>`.
- Implicit cast operators support the conversion of both `T` and
  `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`. `T` converts to `ObjectResult`, which
  means return new `ObjectResult(T);` is simplified to `return T;`.

For more details: [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#actionresultt-type)

Comment: @NiklasHolm I have updated the answer with more clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Third solution: IActionResult Task, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IList<Currency>), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    return Ok(await _typeService.GetCurrenciesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
}

[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetCurrency")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Currency), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute]int id)
{
    return Ok(await _expenseService.GetCurrencyAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false));
}
```

Have a look at an example from Microsoft and why they return the interface instead: [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Examples in MSFT Docs pages are examples of the content described in that doc. Don't consider them as a "best practice" or guideline unless that is the topic of the doc. A lot of times they arent, or are no longer current like this example